# Is there a common high availability solution suite for many products?

Tags: high-availability

I have a doubt that every service could be also highly available.

I want to use Redis and ActiveMQ service and I want to avoid single point of failure. I also need to keep writing data to the Redis and ActiveMQ servers.

I found many articles about MySQL high availability, but only a few about other database solutions, so my question is if there is a common high availability solution suite for many products?

Answer (score 0):

[High availability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability) is one of the principles in [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) and many NoSQL database systems favor rather availability at the expense of data consistency. Replication is often used to achieve high availability for reads, but writes might depend on the type replication being used. Try to look at current [redis replication docs](http://redis.io/topics/replication) or upcoming [redis cluster presentation](http://redis.io/presentation/Redis_Cluster.pdf) for more information on this stuff.